# Changing Script by viewing page source

Tags: php, javascript

We have JavaScript written for form validation.Now my question is that can we change that script permanently by viewing page source. If yes then please tell us how it is possible.Because i think our site has been hacked and hacker is changing that script continuously.

Comment: Hackers can go around javascript validation easily. Form validation should be both client-side and server-side.

Comment: Validate serverside too. The hack is most likely just finding which input parameters are required and there constructing there own request.

Comment: And even non-hackers can do it. :) So, yes, server side validation is a must.

Answer (score 0):

You can't permanently change this by viewing page source. Try to re upload the file with proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do it by just viewing the source code. You need to log in to your file system, and then edit the file where javascript code is written.